Как изменить фотографию и текст, но не отправлять это новым сообщением (редактированием) в aiogram?
Есть функция, которая выводит сообщение с информацией. К этому сообщению прилагаются inline кнопки, одна из которых - "Обновить результаты".  Она вызывает функцию, которая редактирует текст старого сообщения.
with open('graph-progress.png', 'rb') as photo:
                await call.message.answer_photo(photo=photo, caption=f'<b> Твои батл-комнаты:</b>\n', parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=markup_admin_or_basic)



Но получается так, что происходит отправка новым сообщением (что логично)
Я попробовал сделать это через функцию call.message.edit_media, но не получается, и там нет parse_mode, который очень нужен. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать? Хотел разделить два события: сначала редактирование текста, а потом и фотографии. Но потом понял, что в функции call.message.edit_text нельзя отправлять фотографию, а значит, что нельзя в дальнейшем будет изменить её. Как, думаете, можно решить?
